# Inconsistent string literal sharing with GCC

Tags: c++, gcc, string-literals

I've trouble understanding why in this code:

```
#include <cstdio>

void use(const char *msg) { printf("%s\n", msg); }

void bar() { use("/usr/lib/usr/local/foo-bar"); }
void foo() { use("/usr/local/foo-bar"); }

int main() {
    bar();
    foo();
}
```

The compiler (GCC 4.9, in my case) decides to share the string literals:

```
$ g++ -O2 -std=c++11 foo.cpp && strings a.out | grep /usr/
/usr/lib/usr/local/foo-bar
```

Yet in the same, but different situation:

```
#include <cstdio>

void use(const char *msg) { printf("%s\n", msg); }

void bar() { use("/usr/local/var/lib/dbus/machine-id"); } // CHANGED
void foo() { use("/var/lib/dbus/machine-id"); }           // CHANGED

int main() {
    bar();
    foo();
}
```

it doesn't:

```
$ g++ -O2 -std=c++11 foo.cpp && strings a.out | grep /lib/
/usr/local/var/lib/dbus/machine-id
/var/lib/dbus/machine-id
```

***EDIT:***

With `-Os` the second pair of strings are also shared. But that makes no sense. It's just passing pointers. The `lea` with constant offset can hardly be considered worsening performance in such a way as to allow the sharing only in space-optimised mode.

There seems to be a size limit (of 30, incl. the terminating NUL) for string literal sharing. That, too, makes little sense except for maybe avoiding overly long linker runs, trying to find common suffixes.

Comment: Just sounds like a bug, maybe try a few other cases and then file a report?

Comment: I don't see how this is a bug, @CoffeeandCode.

Comment: According to the standard, string literal overlapping is implementation defined, so isn't this up to gcc? Maybe there is a length criteria or smth, but should that cause any issues (apart from the binary size)?

Comment: @Marc: I'm not sure why it chose not to "share" the symbols in the latter case. Only the GCC devs do. Perhaps they can answer you. But, um, why? What _practical problem_ do you face here? tl;dr why do you care

Comment: I wouldn't describe it as a bug, unless it makes the program exhibit different behaviour when executed, which this doesn't.   Compiler optimisations are based on a complex set of criteria - more than (in this case) just recognising and exploiting the existence of common substrings.

Comment: Sure, it's implementation-defined. That doesn't mean the implementation is free to randomly enable or disable the optimisation. Why I care? Because if I didn't, I wouldn't touch a complex language like C++ with a long stick. I'd use Java or Python instead. The point is that sometimes, executable size matters. To the point that you'd rather implement the sharing by hand than leave it to the compiler/linker if it's unreliable. But that can introduce it's own set of problems, so I expect C++ compilers to actually implement all allowed optimisations.

Comment: @MarcMutz-mmutz I checked the generated assembly with an online gcc 4.9 compiler and it does not seem that the strings overlap there.

Comment: FWIW, gcc 4.8.4 / Linux shows the exact behaviour as described in the OP, while gcc 4.9.2 / Cygwin does not share the first pair of literals either. Looks like the implementation changed its definition somewhere. ;)

Comment: @MarcMutz-mmutz: Actually literal sharing is not even *implementation-defined*... the standard states that it is *unspecified* whether two such literals are distinct or not. I.e. the implementation *is* completely at liberty as to how to handle this.

Comment: @RudolfsBundulis: it's the linker which merges the two, not the compiler, thus the use of the `strings` command on the final executable in the OP.

Comment: @MarcMutz-mmutz thanks, at least now I'll be aware of that:) Seems fair that it is up to the linker.

Comment: (very) related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51553606

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~ecj2122/research/gcc_string_literals/gcc_string_literals.pdf) paper has a nice study of gcc and this topic. I personally was not aware of `-fmerge-all-constants`, but you can check if that makes the string overlap in both cases (as the paper states it does not work with `O3` and `Os`).

**EDIT**

Since there was a valid comment, that the answer is link-only (and I meant the answer to be more of just a related information than an actual answer), I felt I needed to make this more extensive. So I tried both samples in http://gcc.godbolt.org/ to see what assembly is generated since I don't have a Linux machine accessible. Strangely enough gcc 4.9 does not merge the strings (or my assembly knowledge is totally wrong), so the question is - can it be specific to your toolchain or maybe the parsing tools fails? See the below images:

[image]
[image]

Of course if I my understanding of the assembly is wrong and `.LC1` and `.LC3` can still overlap in the `.rodata` section then this does not prove anything, but then at least someone will correct me and I'll be aware of this.

Comment: I hate to say it but this is essentially a link-only answer! Can you quote enough of the paper to answer the question?

Comment: Neither `-fmerge-constants` nor `-fmerge-all-constants` have any effect.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, true, objection accepted, and the paper also uses  subjective terms like short/long so citation is kind of meaningless. However I tried checking out the assembly and either the behavior seen by OP is toolchain specific or my assembly knowledge is bad (and it's not good), so comments are very welcome:)

Comment: In this case I felt bad saying it really