# How to stop GCC from combining string literals that share the same suffix?

Tags: c, gcc, elf

GCC seems to do an optimization where it combines string literals that share the same suffix.

For example a C program that contains the two string literals `"foo bar"` and `"bar"` can end up in final *ELF* form (1) the string table changed to have a single string literal `"foo bar"` and (2) the program changed so that any pointer to `"bar"` is converted to now point `4` characters into the string `"foo bar"`.  Note that, from the point of view of a C program reading only forward, the second literal will still look like `"bar"`.

While I think this is a clever scheme for compressing a collection of strings without adding complexity to the format of an *ELF* file, for esoteric reasons it is also causing me problems (while post-processing *ELF* files and doing various analyses on them).  How do I turn off this feature of GCC?

Comment: Try `-fno-merge-constants`?

Comment: have not tried that yet, but even if it worked, we would still like to merge *identical* constants of various kinds, but not merge string constants that are not identical but have the same suffix

Comment: I don't think you have an option there if I recall correctly. You will have one reference to a literal, even if you make use of it more than once (e.g. use `"foo"` multiple times will only result in one literal) -- the option prevents the use of the optimization you describe.

Comment: I think you should explain exactly what problem this is causing you. It can never cause any problem for the running code (as long as it doesn't have undefined behavior) and for whatever post-processing you're doing, there might be a better idea.

Answer (score 8):

The ELF string table is built by the assembler and link editor, so it is not a GCC matter, but rather binutils-related.  String table merging was introduced in binutils 2.26:

- [Inefficient .strtab implementation](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=18451)
- [Use strtab with GC and suffix merging for .strtab](https://sourceware.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=binutils-gdb.git;h=ef10c3ace00674e8c3599c3bf95f06c87d68898b)

This caused occasional issues, for example [when building powerpc64 kernel modules](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=f15838e9cac8f78f0cc506529bb9d3b9fa589c1f).

Unfortunately, I'm not aware of a way to disable string table merging in the BFD-based linker (`ld.bfd`).

However, gold (`ld.gold`, also part of binutils) only performs string table merging when optimizing (at `-O2` and higher; be aware that this is a *linker* flag).  If the binutils assembler merged the string table entries, it will duplicate them again.  This means that if your project is compatible with the gold linker, you can use it to address this problem.