# GCC symbol table optimization - name merge

Tags: c++, c, gcc

I noticed that newer versions of GCC are doing some strange optimizations in the symbol table. This is only happening if there is a name (function or variable) which is a suffix of another name then the compiler only puts the longer name.

For example if there are two functions in the same object with names `LONGER_FUNCTION` and `FUNCTION` then the compiler will put only the `LONGER_FUNCTION` name in the symbol table. For sure if you run an "nm" on the object you get both symbols (I guess the shorter one is referring to the longer one with an offset) but if you run a "strings" on the object file then you get only the longer name `LONGER_FUNCTION`.

This is not the case with the older GCC version (I checked version 4), there all the symbols are listed separably no matter if part of their ending represents another symbol name.

So, this is not a real bug but it is simply a problem in my case since I do some post processing of the object file (do not use "nm") and all the symbols must be listed. If somebody knows how to disable this feature in GCC I'd be very grateful.

Sample code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int LONGER_VARIABLE;
int VARIABLE;
void LONGER_FUNCTION (unsigned char * buf)
{
    if (LONGER_VARIABLE)
        VARIABLE = 0;
}
void FUNCTION (unsigned char * buf)
{
    if (VARIABLE)
        LONGER_VARIABLE = 1;
}
```

gcc -c "c file" -o "obj file"

At the end just run "nm" and "strings" on the object file to see the difference. Preferably use gcc 4 and gcc 7, to see both outputs.

Comment: I bet it's not gcc, but binutils... Gcc doesn't care about such low-level details like generating the ELF sections. Give me some time to check.

Comment: This is since [binutils 2.26](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=18451). There doesn't seem to be a way to disable this behavior. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51553606/703016) suggests using binutils-gold instead.

Comment: @user703016 That is a bummer... I cannot change the binutils... Thanks for pointing out this anyhow.

Comment: I tested the ld.gold, and the newer version is behaving as described in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51551068/how-to-stop-gcc-from-combining-string-literals-that-share-the-same-suffix/51553606#51553606). Then I did a test with ld.gold vesrion "GNU gold (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu 2.26.1) 1.11" (tried different optimizations levels) and it behaves the same as ld.bfd (it merges the symbols). So, the mentioned solution is not always workig.

Comment: Why don't you want to use `nm`? Essentially, the problem of extracting all symbol names from the string table is not difficult given you also have the symbol table (from which there are pointers into the string table that you just have to walk, either manually, or using a tool such as `nm`/`readelf`/`objdump`).

Comment: It is not my choice not to use `nm`. The tool that is doing the post processing was implemented (years ago)  to search for the symbols manually. So, legacy. Anyhow, we are in discussion at the moment to update the tool to use `nm`, since as it looks that is the only way forward (since there is no way to disable the merge in the binutils)