# Ensure that char pointers always point to the same string literal

Tags: c++, c++17

Given the code

```
// somewhere in the program
const char* p1 = "Hello World";

// somewhere else in the program
const char* p2 = "Hello World";
```

is there a way to ensure that `p1 == p2` is always satisfied within the entire program / library? By that I mean that `p1` and `p2` always refer to the same string literal.

## The Reason behind it

What I'm trying to achieve is to use `const char*` as a key for `std::map<const char*, something>`. I have a macro

```
#define nameof(id) #id
```

that mimics the behavior of the `nameof` keyword in C# (I know this is already flawed) and I want to use it to access a registry like structure, for example

```
void foo()
{
    auto x = getMapping(nameof(foo));
}

// different place in code

void registerFoo(something x)
{
    setMapping("foo", x);
}
```

Comment: `assert(p1 == p2);`?

Comment: Not in a portable way.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I don't want to test whether it is satisfied. I want to guarantee that it is always satisfied.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51553606/560648

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Barry shows in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58867003/4342498) the behavior you want is not guaranteed.  You're going to have to pay the cost of string comparisons, but you can at least avoid any memory allocations or writing a comparator by using a [`std::string_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view).  A `std::string_view` is a lightweight view of a string that holds a pointer to the string data and the size of the string and it has a built in `operator <` that will do a lexicographical comparison.  That would change your map to

```
std::map<std::string_view, something>
```

Comment: Definitely the right answer (except in some rare and unknown-to-me scenarios where identity is genuinely what is required)

Answer (score 3):

There is no such requirement. [[lex.string]/15](http://eel.is/c++draft/lex#string-15):

> Whether all string literals are distinct (that is, are stored in nonoverlapping objects) and whether successive evaluations of a string-literal yield the same or a different object is unspecified.

Best you can do is `assert()` or just avoid repeating yourself and stick the thing in a function:

```
char const* my_literal() { return "Hello World"; }

char const* p1 = my_literal();
char const* p2 = my_literal();
```

Comment: Hmm thought so. I've updated my question. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Doesn’t the “successive evaluations” bit mean that `my_literal` might produce different values on each call?  (Even if it’s constexpr!)

Comment: @DavisHerring Yeah... wording issue? Otherwise, that's a fairly hostile, and odr-violation-prone, reading :-)

Comment: @Barry: I actually don’t see how to form an ODR violation from this quirk, given the prohibition on string-literal-related template arguments and the ODR’s token-based checking.  (That doesn’t mean it’s not crazy.)

Comment: @DavisHerring Yeah, maybe not. My default is to assume odr violation.

Answer (score 3):

Identical literal strings are not guaranty to be identical,
but as you use MACRO to create the string, you can change it to return identical string.

gcc/clang have an extension to allow to build UDL from literal string:

```
template<typename Char, Char... Cs>
struct CsHelper
{
    static constexpr const Char s[] = {Cs..., 0}; // The unique address
};

// That template uses the extension
template<typename Char, Char... Cs>
constexpr auto operator"" _cs() -> const Char (&)[1 + sizeof...(Cs)] {
    return CsHelper<Char, Cs...>::s;
}
```

and then

```
#define nameof(id) #id ## _cs
```

See my answer from [String-interning at compiletime for profiling](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50289055/2684539) to have `MAKE_STRING` macro if you cannot used the extension (Really more verbose, and hard coded limit for accepted string length).

Answer (score 1):

There is no requirement that two string literals with the same text are the same object. So the two mentions of `”Hello world”` may or may not refer to a single string in memory. That means that

```
const char* p1 = "Hello World";
const char* p2 = "Hello World";
```

Does not necessarily make `p1` equal to `p2`. To do that, you have to set one of them equal to the other:

```
const char* p2 = p1;
```

But either one of those pointers can be modified, and the other pointer won’t track that change. To make sure that such changes can’t be done, make the pointers const:

```
const char* const p1 = "Hello World";
const char* const p2 = p1;
```

Or, if `p1` needs to be modifiable, make `p2` a reference:

```
const char* p1 = "Hello World";
const char*& p2 = p1;
```

Now `p2` will point at whatever `p1` points at.

Comment: Problem is, `p1` and `p2` have no knowledge of each other,

Comment: @Timo — I wouldn’t have wasted my time if you had said that in your question.

Comment: Well sorry to waste your time but that's why I've written comments in code.

Comment: @Timo — the comments don’t say that.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if it helps, but in `Visual Studio` there is a C++ option called "Enable String Pooling".

[/GF (Eliminate Duplicate Strings)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/gf-eliminate-duplicate-strings?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(VC.Project.VCCLCompilerTool.StringPooling)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=msvc-170)

> Enables the compiler to create a single copy of identical strings in
> the program image and in memory during execution. This is an
> optimization called string pooling that can create smaller programs.