# How to pass const char[] arrays as constexpr template parameters using C++ STL libraries?

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, c++17, c++20

I have this working code for **`C++ 17`** standard:

```cpp
template< int PathIndex, int PathLength, const char (path)[PathLength] >
constexpr const int findlastslash()
{
    if constexpr( PathIndex < 1 || path[PathIndex] == '/' || path[PathIndex] == '\\' ) {
        return PathIndex;
    }
    else {
        return findlastslash<PathIndex - 1, PathLength, path>();
    }
}

template< int PathLength, const char (path)[PathLength] >
constexpr const int startfindlastslash()
{
    return findlastslash< PathLength - 1, PathLength, path >();
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    static constexpr const char path[7] = "c/test";
    static_assert( startfindlastslash< 7, path >() == 1, "Fail!" );
}
```

I would like to stop writing/hard coding the **`constexpr`** array size **`7`**, i.e., make the template meta-programming deduce by itself the **`constexpr const char[]`** array size instead of having to write the size everywhere. For example, given something looking like the following:

```cpp
template< int PathIndex, int PathLength, const char (path)[PathLength] >
constexpr const int findlastslash()
{
    if constexpr( PathIndex < 1 || path[PathIndex] == '/' || path[PathIndex] == '\\' ) {
        return PathIndex;
    }
    else {
        return findlastslash<PathIndex - 1, PathLength, path>();
    }
}

template< const char (path)[PathLength] >
constexpr const int startfindlastslash()
{
    return findlastslash< PathLength - 1, PathLength, path >();
}

template<int PathLength>
constexpr const char path[PathLength] = "c/test";

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    static_assert( startfindlastslash< path >() == 1, "Fail!" );
}
```

Of course, the code just above is utterly invalid. However, it is a good approximation of a easy way to describe things.

How would you solve this problem? Would you replace **`constexpr const char path[7] = "c/test";`** by a **`std::array`** or **`std::string_view`**?

I tried building this code using **`std::string_view`**:

```cpp
#include <string_view>

template< int PathIndex, std::string_view path >
constexpr const int findlastslash()
{
    if constexpr( PathIndex < 1 || path[PathIndex] == '/' || path[PathIndex] == '\\' ) {
        return PathIndex;
    }
    else {
        return findlastslash<PathIndex - 1, path>();
    }
}

template< std::string_view path >
constexpr const int startfindlastslash()
{
    return findlastslash< path.length() - 1, path >();
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    static constexpr std::string_view path{"c/test"};
    static_assert( startfindlastslash< path >() == 1, "Fail!" );
}
```

But it does not compile:

1. **`g++ -o main.exe --std=c++17 test_debugger.cpp`**

   ```
   test_debugger.cpp:3:43: error: ‘class std::basic_string_view<char>’ is not a valid type for a template non-type parameter
    template< int PathIndex, std::string_view path >
                                              ^~~~
   test_debugger.cpp:14:28: error: ‘class std::basic_string_view<char>’ is not a valid type for a template non-type parameter
    template< std::string_view path >
                               ^~~~
   test_debugger.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, const char**)’:
   test_debugger.cpp:22:47: error: no matching function for call to ‘startfindlastslash<path>()’
        static_assert( startfindlastslash< path >() == 1, "Fail!" );
                                                  ^
   test_debugger.cpp:15:21: note: candidate: template<<typeprefixerror>path> constexpr const int startfindlastslash()
    constexpr const int startfindlastslash()
                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   test_debugger.cpp:15:21: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
   test_debugger.cpp:22:47: note: invalid template non-type parameter
        static_assert( startfindlastslash< path >() == 1, "Fail!" );
                                                  ^
   ```
2. **`clang++ -Xclang -ast-print -fsyntax-only --std=c++17 test_debugger.cpp > main.exe`**

   ```
   test_debugger.cpp:3:43: error: a non-type template parameter cannot have type 'std::string_view' (aka 'basic_string_view<char>')
   template< int PathIndex, std::string_view path >
                                             ^
   test_debugger.cpp:14:28: error: a non-type template parameter cannot have type 'std::string_view' (aka 'basic_string_view<char>')
   template< std::string_view path >
                              ^
   test_debugger.cpp:15:21: error: no return statement in constexpr function
   constexpr const int startfindlastslash()
                       ^
   test_debugger.cpp:22:20: error: no matching function for call to 'startfindlastslash'
       static_assert( startfindlastslash< path >() == 1, "Fail!" );
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   test_debugger.cpp:15:21: note: candidate template ignored: invalid explicitly-specified argument for template parameter 'path'
   constexpr const int startfindlastslash()
                       ^
   4 errors generated.
   ```

**Note:** I am not interested in finding the last slash on the string as the algorithm is doing. I just took this silly example as an excuse to learn better what can and cannot be done with constexpr template parameters.

For reference, on [(C++20) String literals as non-type template parameters example?](https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/bhxx49/c20_string_literals_as_nontype_template/) I found this example code doing something cool with **`C++ 20`**: (https://godbolt.org/z/L0J2K2)

```cpp
template<unsigned N>
struct FixedString {
    char buf[N + 1]{};
    constexpr FixedString(char const* s) {
        for (unsigned i = 0; i != N; ++i) buf[i] = s[i];
    }
    constexpr operator char const*() const { return buf; }
};
template<unsigned N> FixedString(char const (&)[N]) -> FixedString<N - 1>;

template<FixedString T>
class Foo {
    static constexpr char const* Name = T;
public:
    void hello() const;
};

int main() {
    Foo<"Hello!"> foo;
    foo.hello();
}
```

Do I really need to define my own **`FixedString`** class? The **`C++ STL`** (Standard Template Library) does not have anything which can be used instead for this common/simple task?

For reference, I found this nice related third part libraries:

1. https://github.com/irrequietus/typestring for **`C++11/14 strings for direct use in template parameter lists, template metaprogramming`**.
2. https://github.com/hanickadot/compile-time-regular-expressions **`A Compile time PCRE (almost) compatible regular expression matcher.`**

Comment: Please stop saying “constexpr template parameters”—there isn’t any other kind.

Comment: @DavisHerring, It is a **`pleonasm`** to empathize and make it pretty obvious. If I just said **`template parameters`** someone could think about this: **`template<int Size> function(const char (&name)[Size])`** instead of something like **`template<const char (name)[Size]> function()`**. But as I added it has to be **`constexpr`**, there is no way it could be the former because function parameters cannot be **`constexpr`**.

Comment: For the given example, `template< std::sise_t N>
constexpr int find_last_slash(const char (&s)[N])` would do the job. (and [`consteval`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/consteval) in C++20 to avoid possible runtime calls).

Comment: @user: "*If I just said template parameters someone could think about this: template<int Size> function(const char (&name)[Size]) instead of something like template<const char (name)[Size]> function().*" And they would be wrong to think that because `name` would not be a template parameter. This is why there is a distinction between "template parameter" and "function parameter".

Comment: @Jarod42, If I understand correctly, you already did it when you wrote that example originally, but it would not be possible to use the modification I added, i.e., using the **`const char(&s)[N]`** directly in a constexpr.

Comment: there's no  constexpr const ... , use either one

Comment: @nonock, For reference, **`constexpr`** is an abbreviation to **`constant expression`**. We could call **`constexpr const`** a compiler pleonasm. The compiler did not get in my way making my life miserable when I used it for the first time, then I just kept going with it «~‿~»

Comment: @user: By definition, a "pleonasm" represents a thing that is it is unnecessarily verbose and thus serves no actual purpose, so you should stop doing it because it merely takes up space without communicating useful information.

Comment: @NicolBolas, You are right. I stopped adding it. At the beginning it was fun, but after a while it get boring.

Comment: @NicolBolas, After I removed the `const` from my `constexpr const char*`, the compiler started complaining: **`warning: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]`**, so I am adding my **`constexpr const`** back.

Comment: @user: Don't forget how `const` works with pointers. `const char *` says that the `char` is `const`, not the pointer. `constexpr T*` says that the pointer is a constant expression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I would like to stop writing/hard coding the constexpr array size 7

In C++17, you might use `auto` as non template parameter and get rid of hard-coded `7`:

```
template <std::size_t PathIndex, const auto& path>
constexpr std::size_t findlastslash()
{
    if constexpr (PathIndex < 1 || path[PathIndex] == '/' || path[PathIndex] == '\\') {
        return PathIndex;
    }
    else {
        return findlastslash<PathIndex - 1, path>();
    }
}

template <const auto& path>
constexpr std::size_t startfindlastslash()
{
    return findlastslash<std::extent_v<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(path)>> - 1, path >();
}

int main() {
    static constexpr const char path[] = "c/test";
    static_assert(startfindlastslash<path>() == 1, "Fail!" );
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4abab43d46c840ef)

You might "protect" the `auto` with SFINAE or with concept (C++20):

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
constexpr std::true_type is_c_array_impl(const T(&)[N]) { return {}; }

template <typename T>
constexpr std::false_type is_c_array_impl(const T&) { return {}; }

template <typename T>
constexpr auto is_c_array() -> decltype(is_c_array_impl(std::declval<const T&>())) {return {};}

template <typename T>
concept CArrayRef = (bool) is_c_array<const T&>() && std::is_reference_v<T>;

template <std::size_t PathIndex, const auto& path>
constexpr std::size_t findlastslash() requires (CArrayRef<decltype(path)>)
{
    if constexpr (PathIndex < 1 || path[PathIndex] == '/' || path[PathIndex] == '\\') {
        return PathIndex;
    }
    else {
        return findlastslash<PathIndex - 1, path>();
    }
}

template <const auto& path>
constexpr std::size_t startfindlastslash() requires (CArrayRef<decltype(path)>)
{
    return findlastslash<std::extent_v<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(path)>> - 1, path >();
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f14e1b65feab5d27)

> Do I really need to define my own `FixedString` class? The C++ STL (Standard Template Library) does not have anything which can be used instead for this common/simple task?

It seems there is not currently equivalent to `FixedString`.

Comment: Fair answer! But I forgot to tell I do not like using auto because makes the code less clear. It is like reading Python code where usually there are no types (unless you use the latest version which allows you to add type tags). If it will help in any way, I would rather define myself some class as the example **`FixedString`** which I presented in the question, rather than use auto.

Comment: C++20 would allow concept, so you might have `CharArray` instead of `auto`, but `FixedString` seems superior.

Comment: Prior to C++20, as already mentioned in another of your question, you might create [char sequence type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58868005/2684539).

Comment: If I understand correctly, that is only a extension for clang/gcc. I rather use something which can work with any compiler complaint with the standard.

Comment: Can you give an example about how it would be using concept?

Comment: gcc/clang extension, or MACRO usage (with hard coded length limit).

Comment: Thanks! Can you add the codo into this answer or a new answer? It is just in case that web site go off-line/dead some day. In that case, the code would be lost.

Comment: This concept does not work in Visual Studio with C++20 enabled. It says `'startfindlastslash': the associated constraints are not satisfied`

Comment: @Youda008: extra parents fixes the issue [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/EcrhbvY9v).

Comment: I don't know why, but msvc is inconsistent on `decltype(path)` [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/x17EKMdKx).

Answer (score 0):

For what it is worth, here it is an example using the `FixedString` class presented on the question. Sadly, this only compiles with GCC 9.1 or above. Not even Clang 9 or Clang trunk as of today can build this as it requires C++20 features.

https://godbolt.org/z/eZy2eY (for GCC 9.1)

```cpp
template<unsigned N>
struct FixedString
{
    char buf[N + 1]{};
    int length = N;

    constexpr FixedString(char const* string)
    {
        for (unsigned index = 0; index < N; ++index) {
            buf[index] = string[index];
        }
    }
    constexpr operator char const*() const { return buf; }
};

template<unsigned N>
FixedString(char const (&)[N]) -> FixedString<N - 1>;
```

```cpp
template< int PathIndex, FixedString path >
constexpr const int findlastslash()
{
    if constexpr( PathIndex < 1 || path[PathIndex] == '/' || path[PathIndex] == '\\' ) {
        return PathIndex;
    }
    else {
        return findlastslash<PathIndex - 1, path>();
    }
}

template< FixedString path >
constexpr const int startfindlastslash() 
{
    return findlastslash< path.length - 1, path >();
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    static_assert( startfindlastslash< "c/test" >() == 1, "Fail!" );
}
```