# Concatenate const char at compile time when one of them is a function parameter

Tags: c++, c++17, constexpr

I'm trying to add a filename prefix to each log string in spdlog.
The Spdlog formatting string looks as this:

`Test log {}`

Logs are written as this:
`spdlog::error("Test log {}", value)`

I'm trying to wrap this call and concatenate additional {} before formatting string, so I can pass the prefix of the file there.

```
static constexpr char * prefixHolder("{} ");

template<typename... Args>
void critical(const char fmt[], Args&&... args) const
{
    constexpr auto fullFmt = prefixHolder + fmt; //I can't find any solution for this

    spdlog::critical(fullFmt, m_prefix, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}


Log log("MyClassOrLogger");

log.critical("My format {}", value);
```

Is it possible to solve this at compile time? I've tried some approaches, but I haven't found any way to make input fmt argument constexpr for the compiler.

C++ 17

Any suggestions or solutions?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parameter value cannot be used for constexpr.

You might turn:

```
template<typename... Args>
constexpr void critical(const char fmt[], Args&&... args)
```

into

```
template <char... cs, typename... Args>
void critical(std::integer_sequence<char, cs...>, Args&&... args)
{
    constexpr char fullFmt[] = {'{', '}', ' ', cs... , '\0'};

    spdlog::critical(fullFmt, m_prefix, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

to allow to have constexpr char array.

[ensure-that-char-pointers-always-point-to-the-same-string-literal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58868005/2684539) shows way to create similar sequences from literal string.
In your case, it would be:

```
template <typename Char, Char... Cs>
constexpr auto operator"" _cs() -> std::integer_sequence<Char, Cs...> {
    return {};
}
```

Usage is then something like:

```
log.critical("My format {}"_cs, value); // gcc extension
log.critical(MAKE_SEQUENCE("My format {}"), value);
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/4v7Wro) with gcc extension.
[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/a547Ex) with MACRO.

Comment: It converts _cs literal to const char[] by some reason  
`error: no matching function for call to 'Log::critical(const char [6])'
    logger.critical("Hello"_cs);`

MAKE_STRING example is missing aligned_string. I found a similar implementation but with 2 template parameters in one of your replies, but it fails to compile for me still. The same issue as with _cs.
gcc 7.3.1
@Jarod42

Comment: Code in links need some adaptations, [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/4v7Wro) with gcc extension.

Comment: Can you help with the MAKE_STRING example? The portability of the extension variant concerns me.

Comment: [string-interning-at-compiletime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50288847/string-interning-at-compiletime-for-profiling/50289055#50289055) provides `MAKE_CHAR_SEQUENCE` which give a `template <char...Cs> struct char_sequence` that you can use instead of `std::integer_sequence<char, ..>`. Else you can create traits to transform the former into the later.

Comment: Portable demo added.

Comment: Is there really no way or secret trick to write extra code that allows to drop the ugly `_cs` or `MAKE_SEQUENCE`? Can one use somehow implicit conversion from constexpr const char* to std::integer_sequence with correct deduced template parameters? And in C++23?

Comment: Even `consteval` doesn't allow to use parameter as `constexpr`.

Answer (score 0):

An old-time method using implicit string literal concatenation during compile time, often used in the case of multi-line strings:

```cpp
#define HELLO_WORLD "Hello" " World" // -> Hello World

# define MULTI_LINE "Hello" \
    " World"                         // -> Hello World
```

You can use compile time log level macros of spdlog, might be:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

#define SPDLOG_ERROR(...)  printf(__VA_ARGS__) // a dummy macro of spdlog

#define YOUR_prefixHolder "{} "
#define YOUR_ERROR1(fmt, ...) SPDLOG_ERROR(YOUR_prefixHolder fmt, ##__VA_ARGS__);
#define YOUR_ERROR2(...) SPDLOG_ERROR(YOUR_prefixHolder __VA_ARGS__);

int main()
{
    YOUR_ERROR1("I have %u apples\n", 5); // {} I have 5 apples
    YOUR_ERROR2("I have %u apples\n", 5); // {} I have 5 apples
    
    YOUR_ERROR1(5); // error!
    SPDLOG_ERROR(5) // 5
}
```